# SharePoint 2010 Create sample WorkFlow on Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

Am totally new to WorkFlows in SharePoint 2010. I know the question could be too basic. but please help me sorting this out.

I have SharePoint 2010 web application have Groups: Presenters and Approvers. Presenters need to submit presentation slides and Approvers approves/rejects it. I have a document library to which the presentations are uploaded. When a presenter uploads a presentation, an email notification has to be sent to the Approvers group. The Approvers review the presentation and approves/rejects the presentation, an email is sent to the presenter notifying the Approver's response.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com ? That said, you should move on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Via SharePoint Designer 2010, you can easily attach a approval workflow (OOB) to your document library.

Your wf will handle action based on Document library item value.

If the item value (field Approbation status) equal Approved => send mail ok to presenter

If the item value (field Approbation status) equal Rejected => send mail ko to presenter

etc...

More details : http://blog.sharepoint-videos.com/workflow-designer-in-sharepoint-designer-2010/

Comment: Created a workflow to send mail on item created. my workflow showing error: "The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly." I have configured the outgoing email setting to smtp.gmail.com.

Comment: First step, try to send mail from another part of your SharePoint site.

Comment: Second step, smtp.gmail.com, this smtp server allow send email with anonymous access ?  allow e-mail messages to be relayed ?